# VB.Net Binary Serialization Exception

Tags: vb.net, binaryformatter

I'm Serializing and Deserializing an Overlay Object from / to local disk with a BinaryFormatter; however i have an exception that is showing each time i rebuilt my project, at Design Time.

Type [A] is not not Compatible with Type [B], given that theses instances are each operating in different assembly wich i found in :

C:....\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ProjectAssemblies

Each time i Rebuilding my project, an instance is created there.

Is There any propety that can set BinaryFormatter to be more flexible since these instances are VS created assemblies that are different from my project folder?
thank you

Comment: If your class is small, prefer XML, as the BinaryFormatter conversions is strong-typed.

Comment: If you are trying to serialize in one assembly and deserialize in another, the BinaryFormatter wont do.  [ProtoBuf-NET](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) is a superb replacement: smaller output, faster and assembly agnostic

Comment: Protobuf is good i guess, however, that should not be a problem at all, since VS should be able to bypass theses kind of problems , given that as a developper , you wory about your current application.

Comment: No, the BinaryFormatter is designed to only deserialize to the same Class-Assembly-Culture-Version.  There are workaraounds, but Protobuf is intended for data exchange where BF is not.

Comment: it is the same Assembya Single Project, at least for me; it's the same project;if i choose o use Protobuf, have i any resrictions with its license (Apache 2.0) ?

Answer (score 0):

After Trying lot Of things, i opted for a Design mode Check to avoid that the Visual Studio Designer serialization incompatibility Exception :

```
If Not DesignMode Then
        GWCamerasUtilities.LoadCamerasOverlay()
End If
```

My Next Projects will certainly relay on Protobuf as suggested by [Plutonix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070452/plutonix)